# How to know in which module am I from root component?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-routing

my application is consists of multi-systems (modules),that are lazy loaded, and inside app.component.ts I need to know which module the current url belongs to!

for example:
both below urls are belong to the "Contacts" module

```
http://localhost:4200/Contacts/ContactsList 
http://localhost:4200/Contacts/NewContact
```

can I attach routes with data, and how to do that when using lazy loading, and how to access those data?

Answer (score 0):

Using [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRouteSnapshot) you can get the parameters.

```
@Component({templateUrl:'./my-component.html'})
 class MyComponent {
   constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
      const id: string = route.snapshot.params.id;
      const url: string = route.snapshot.url.join('');
      const user = route.snapshot.data.user;
 }
}
```

Comment: thanks, do I need to do this inside every component? can I control this management from single place ?

Comment: Yes you have to add this to every component to get the relevant parameters for that particular component.

Comment: thanks, I'm sorry I didn't tried this code yet, I reorganized my application to get what I want.